# Returning the name of the key that has the largest value in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

The challenge is to return the name of the province that has the largest population. I created a nested dictionary

```
this_dict = {"Ontario": {"capital": "Toronto", "largest": "Toronto", "population": "14734014"},
             "Quebec": {"capital": "Quebec City", "largest": "Montreal", "population": "8574571"},
             "Nova Scotia": {"capital": "Halifax", "largest": "Halifax", "population": "979351"},
             "New Brunswick": {"capital": "Fredericton", "largest": "Moncton", "population": "781476"},
             "Manitoba": {"capital": "Winnipeg", "largest": "Winnipeg", "population": "1379263"},
             "British Columbia": {"capital": "Victoria", "largest": "Vancouver", "population": "5147712"},
             "Prince Edward Island": {"capital": "Charlottetown", "largest": "Charlottetown", "population": "159625"},
             "Saskatchewan": {"capital": "Regina", "largest": "Saskatoon", "population": "1178681"},
             "Alberta": {"capital": "Edmonton", "largest": "Calgary", "population": "4421876"},
             "Newfoundland and Labrador": {"capital": "St. John's", "largest": "St. John's", "population": "522103"}

             }
```

I created a function and my code so far:

```
 def get_largest_city():
    max_population = max([int(i['population']) for i in this_dict.values()])
    print(max_population)
```

This gives me the the number of the province that has the largest number which is 14734014
However, the output I want is for it to return the name of the province instead which in this case should be Ontario.

I'd appreciate any opinions on this, I'm pretty new with Python and just gets confused at times sorry if this isn't explained in the most ideal way and thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Why write a function that *prints* rather than *returns* its value?

Comment: I honestly was not sure on how to do it, I'm trying different approach and just need some directions... :/

Comment: you want to do that with list comprehension?

Comment: @Tuqay list comprehension would be great to get a shorter code that works but honestly any input would help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```py
>>> max(this_dict, key=lambda k: int(this_dict[k]["population"]))
'Ontario'
```

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at this. Sorry if that wasn't clear, either it returns Toronto or Ontario as an output would work.

Comment: Actually this is a bit unclear in the question: OP said they want "name of the province which should be Toronto", but Toronto is actually one of the capitals, not a province. Provinces are the keys of the outer dict. I assumed OP wanted the province.

Comment: @Czaporka sorry about that i'll edit my question in a bit. Either actually would work but you're right it should be the province name. Thanks a lot, appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You must use the `key` argument of the [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) built-in:

```
def get_largest_city():
    max_population = max(this_dict.items(), key=lambda item: int(item[1]["population"]))
    return max_population[1]["capital"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I tried this and just got a yellow warning: Expected type 'Union[int, slice]', got 'str' instead :/

Comment: That must be a pylint warning, you can ignore it for this case.

Comment: Will do. Thanks again, appreciate it.